# How to permanently attach a sqlite database to the main database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two database files in different paths.
I link both databases with the following statement:

```
$ sqlite3 notesDB.db
sqlite> .databases
main: C:\Users\Proyects\Apps\Aplicacions\Principal\App_Notes\db\notesDB.db r/w
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'userDB.db' AS userDB1;
sqlite> .databases
main: C:\Users\Proyects\Apps\Aplicacions\Principal\App_Notes\db\notesDB.db r/w
userDB1: C:\Users\Proyects\Apps\Aplicacions\Principal\App_Notes\db1\userDB.db r/w
```

So far everything works fine. The problem is that when I leave the database, that link is lost and I have to attach `userDb1` again. Is it possible to attach a sqlite database permanently?

Comment: The `attach` command attaches another database to the database *connection*, not to the database. As such it is lost when you disconnect. To my knowledge there is no way to permanently link two databases, you can only attach.

Comment: Ok, I´ll do it every time I make a connection.
Thank you very much!